# SQL view to create dynamic column with case

Tags: sql

I have below SQL query where I am trying to query same table but with different conditions. I am trying to speed up the output to filter output.

```
select column1, column2 
from table 
where column2 like abc 
  and column3 = '1' 

select column1, column2 
from table 
where column2 like abc 
  and column4 = '1' 
  and column5 = 'car' 

select column1, column2 
from table
where column2 like abc 
  and column6 = 'country' 
  and column7 = 'food'
```

I am looking for a switch case to create a view with additional column 10 and put an entry for the out put of first query and do the same for subsquent queries.

Final view should be like this,

```
column1 column2 column3 
Red     Mar     Rule1 
Blue    Earth   Rule2
Green   Venus   Rule2 
White   Pluto   Rule1 
Pink    Jupitor Rule2
```

Sample example:

```
SELECT column1, column2, CASE WHEN column2 like '%abc%' and column3 = '1' 
THEN 'Rule1' WHEN column2 like '%abc%' and column4 = '1' and column5 = 'car' 
THEN 'Rule2' WHEN column2 like '%abc%' and column6 = 'country' amd column7 = 'food' 
THEN 'Rule3' END AS RuleName FROM table
```

Comment: Sorry, I hope someone else understands.. I can't figure out what you have, what you need nor what your question is.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?